# To use Reed switch to switch DC supply to a relay coil...what precautions to take?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply

I wish to use a reed switch the contacts of which will switch the coil of a relay with coil voltage of 12 volts ( Coil resistance 160 Ohms)  or 24 volts DC (Coil resistance 640 Ohms). I prefer  to use a 24 volt relay  being commonly available but my impression is that the contacts of the reed switches are rated at 20 Volts DC.

Any other precaution is needed to prevent damage to the reed switch ?
The load on the relay is a pump motor of say 1/2 to 1 HP.

Comment: Have you considered using the reed switch to control a BJT/MOSFET that would switch the coil of your relay?

Comment: A reed switch is reliable and long lasting of you do not cause contact erosion.  A relay coil is an inductive load and can be hard work on the reed switch.  If you select rather a more beefy reed switch and/or switch to AC operation on the switch (you can rectify it for the relay is required) you should be better served than operating very close to the rated limits.  It also depends on how expensive a call-out to replace the reed switch would be.

Answer (score 5):

As per my comment

[image]

Reed switch only see a 12V signal and the current through it is small (mA). R4 ensures that the BJT is kept off when the switch is open.